# How to configure IF function to dynamically display three data tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, interactive

I downloaded the Microsoft Office Excel Template called "**Vehicle Log Book**" and I'm having trouble adjusting the graph so it includes 3 items in the drop down list, instead of 2.

I believe the issue is the IF Function, which is preventing the third data table from displaying on the graph. The dynamic chart is currently using *=IF(PlotChoice="GAS",1,2)*

Can anyone provide feedback on what I need to change the "IF" function to so all three data tables display? I tried changing it to =IF(PlotChoice="GAS",1,2,3), but I get a "Too Many Arguments Were Entered" error message.

Here is a link to the updated worksheet: https://yale.box.com/s/jqqwepjj0czzdz7sixsih3g3qok5nyld

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: The IF statement can only have two outcomes True or False. IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])  Have you heard of nesting an IF statement?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you did not design that workbook, otherwise there would be no such mystery.

IF works like this: `IF(Condition,Result when true, Result when false)`.

`=IF(PlotChoice="GAS",1,2)`

If the range name "PlotChoice" equals "Gas", then return 1, else return 2.
The result is one of two possible values. If you need to select between three, then you need to nest the IF Statements.

`=IF(PlotChoice="GAS",1,IF(PlotChoice="Maintenance",2, 3))`

If the range name "PlotChoice" equals "Gas", then return 1, else there is another IF(). If the range name "PlotChoice" equals "Maintenance" then return 2, else return 3.

You can continue this kind of nesting for more levels than is advisable. For scenarios with more than three or four possible outcomes there are more efficient and maintainable options.